# product of sums

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, inequality

This is a question which has puzzled me for a while. I would be very thankful if somebody can help me with it.

Assume you have $S$ rectangles appearing in front of your screen one by one. Each rectangle has the same area $A$ but not necessarily the same width and height. The first rectangle has width $w_{1}$ and height $h_{1}=A/w_{i}$, the second width $w_{2}$ and height $h_{2}=A/w_{2}$ etc. Then, the following inequality obviously holds:

$S\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{S}(w_{i}\cdot h_{i})\leq (\sum_{i=1}^{S}w_{i})\cdot(\sum_{j=1}^{S}h_{j})$. Note the left hand side is equal to $S^{2}\cdot A$.

My question is the following:

Assume, now, that the area is not necessarily the same, e.g you do not have a bijection between two elements of the two sets $W$ and $H$. You still have $S$ rectangles, the first with area $A_{1}\leq A$, the second with area $A_{2}\leq A$,... and the $S$-th with area $A_{S}\leq A$.

Assuming that the $i$-th rectangle has width $w_{i}$ and height $h_{i}$, the next one ($i+1$) has either:

1. **height $h_{i+1}=h_{i}-1$ and width $w_{i+1}=w_{i}$** or
2. **height $h_{i+1}\geq h_{i}$ and width $w_{i+1}=A/h_{i+1}$**.

Can you say that $S\cdot(A_{1}+...+A_{S})\leq (\sum_{i=1}^{S}w_{i})\cdot(\sum_{j=1}^{S}h_{j})$ now?

Thank you.

Comment: Your 2nd case seems a bit odd because $w_{i+1}$ can't be greater than $w_i$. You see, if your 2nd case takes place than $A \geqslant w_{i+1}h_{i+1} = w_{i+1}\cdot \dfrac{A}{w_i} \geqslant w_i\cdot \dfrac{A}{w_i} = A$. So $w_{i+1}h_{i+1} = A$ and $w_{i+1} = \cfrac{A}{h_{i+1}} = w_i$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I mistyped it. Thanks! It should be: 1. height $h_{i+1}=h_{i}-1$ and width $w_{i+1}=w_{i}$ or 2. height $h_{i+1}\geq h_{i}$ and width $w_{i+1}=A/h_{i+1}$. I am editing it

Comment: Now your desired inequality doesn't hold for $S = 2$, $A = 4$, $w_1 = 1$, $h_1 = 1$, $w_2 = 2$, $h_2 = 2$ because it turns into $2\cdot (1 + 4) \leqslant (1 + 1)\cdot (2 + 2)$ which is clearly false.

Comment: You are correct. It is my mistake that I haven't explained rigorously the problem. Initially (time t=1) each rectangle has an area of $A$ and then either (1) or (2) takes place. If (2) takes place then the area is set to $A$. If (1) takes place the area decreases by $w_{i}$ per time step. But I better do not waste your time with a problem I did not explain as properly as I should :) Thanks again, though!

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear. In counterexample above all given conditions like $A_i \leqslant A$, either (1) or (2) takes place, are met.

Comment: You start with a rectangle of area 1, whilst you should have been starting with a rectangle of area 4. So, assuming you start with $w_{1}=2, h_{1}=2$ at time $t=1$, at $t=2$ you get either $h_{2}=1, w_{2}=2$ or again $w_{2}=h_{2}=2$. You may think of this problem as a sequence of appearing rectangles that each one has either area $A$ or its area is trimmed at each subsequent time step $t_{i+1}$ by $w_{i}$ (since the length decreases by 1). Thanks for your help